# What's a word that describes something that is obvious but you didn't think of in the first place?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a word that describes something that is obvious but you didn't think of in the first place? Usually this happens when someone points out something and you're pleasantly surprised/shocked by the discovery

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The idiom is *”it was staring you in the face the whole time*”  not sure there’s a word apart from maybe *obvious (in hindsight)*

Comment: If you can express it with an interjection, *duh* works well.

Comment: Kindly provide usage example. You can also provide a fill-in-the-blank sentence. I could think of two words and providing them below in the form of an answer. Use more words, sentences to make clear your exact requirement from the word/s.

Answer (score 0):

[Oblivious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblivious) and/or [Hiding in plain sight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hide+in+plain+sight).

These two words may serve your purpose.

[Oblivious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblivious) (Wiktionary)Lacking awareness; unmindful; unaware, unconscious of. Failing to remember; forgetful.

[Hiding in plain sight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hide+in+plain+sight) (The Free Dictionary by Farlex) Concealed or unseen despite being in full, unrestricted view.